# Border radius looking blur

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Css border radius looking blur(pixel out).i used css

```
border: 1px solid #8d2034;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 27px;
height: 27px !important;
/* float: left; */
text-align: center;
padding: 0px !important;
line-height: 26px;
margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
```

Within anchor tag i have an element ,i tried adding border-radius to this anchor tag but it doesnot seem to work .Can someone please help.please check this attachment [image: reference]

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: i am using css3 border radius property for anchor tag.in anhor tag i am using <i class="fa"></i>.border radius not working properly.please check attachment once

Answer (score 0):

```css
i.fa{
  color: #8d2034;
  border: 1px solid #8d2034;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
```